# Detect other devices with google maps

Tags: android, google-maps, mobile

I need to implement in an app the detection of other devices with the same app in a certain range (let's say about 10km). I am familiar with gmaps JS API, but if this can't be done in JS it's not a problem. I don't need the code, I just need the idea of communicating betweeen devices. I don't really know how to approach this part.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume that in most cases of this model, there is a server sitting somewhere, and that each device running the app periodically makes a call to that server with a "this is where I am located, what other devices running the app are nearby?" message.

Pretty straight forward http API calls **if** you have a server that is the central repository of "what device is currently where?" information.

Comment: Yes, it has a server. I was thinking about this but if there are many devices isn't the server overloaded with requests?

Comment: Only seemed to get a piece of your response, but if there are many devices, a good API will let you choose what "nearby" means (1km, 5km, 10km), or might let you set a maximum number of devices to return, and ideally return them in closest to furthest order. If it doesn't, you can always implement the throttling on your side by geographic distance, or processing only the first n devices in the response.  If it's a server managing real-time geographic data, then it should be designed to do so well. Device polling frequency lets you manage the request load per device.

Comment: Sorry if was unclear. Yes the "nearby" should work but I have many devices running the app at the same time so that's my concern about overloading the server with multiple calls. The app usually should return 1 device to many. It detects one that approaches the others and signals them.